# jQuery fadeout element on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a wordpress site that when a form is filled out, if an error is thrown then the plugin shows a `<span>` with the error text within.

Im trying to fade that text out using jQuery and I have tried both the following to no avail...

```
$(".wpcf7-not-valid-tip").on("mouseenter", function(){
        alert( 'test');
});
$('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').hover(
      function () {
       $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

My HTML markup is being outputted as so...

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap telno">
    <input type="text" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required field wpcf7-not-valid" value="" name="telno">
    <span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">Please fill the required field.</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SybUV/

Comment: exactly! just checked on fiddle and it's all right

Comment: Is the event being bound after document is ready? If not, it may not be getting bound at all. Try using $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').live('mouseenter', function() {//whatever})

Comment: +1 with the "Seems to be working" crowd (http://jsfiddle.net/KpFeF/). If you're not having luck, then there is likely another JS error someplace. +1 to @benastan for reading my mind. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you are binding the events before the item exists?

try this and see if you have more luck

```
$('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').live('mouseenter', function(ev) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

or

```
$(".wpcf7-not-valid-tip").on("mouseenter", function(ev){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I guess you added the `.on` example in your question as I was answering the question.